# bacula chooses wrong storage on restore

Tags: bacula

I have Bacula server that uses 2 storages. 
I'm trying to restore file with the steps

```
root@archive:/etc/bacula/clients# bconsole
Connecting to Director 1.1.1.1:9101
1000 OK: archive.blablabla Version: 5.2.6 (21 February 2012)
Enter a period to cancel a command.
*messages
You have no messages.
*restore
The defined Catalog resources are:
 1: MyCatalog
 2: catalog_blablabla_ru
Select Catalog resource (1-2): 1'
Expected a positive integer, got: 1'
Select Catalog resource (1-2): 1
Using Catalog "MyCatalog"
First you select one or more JobIds that contain files
to be restored. You will be presented several methods
of specifying the JobIds. Then you will be allowed to
select which files from those JobIds are to be restored.

To select the JobIds, you have the following choices:
  1: List last 20 Jobs run
  2: List Jobs where a given File is saved
  3: Enter list of comma separated JobIds to select
  4: Enter SQL list command
  5: Select the most recent backup for a client
  6: Select backup for a client before a specified time
  7: Enter a list of files to restore
  8: Enter a list of files to restore before a specified time
  9: Find the JobIds of the most recent backup for a client
 10: Find the JobIds for a backup for a client before a specified time
 11: Enter a list of directories to restore for found JobIds
 12: Select full restore to a specified Job date
 13: Cancel
Select item:  (1-13): 12
Enter JobId to get the state to restore: 816
Selecting jobs to build the Full state at 2015-09-18 22:02:41
You have selected the following JobId: 816

Building directory tree for JobId(s) 816 ...
11 files inserted into the tree.

You are now entering file selection mode where you add (mark) and
remove (unmark) files to be restored. No files are initially added, unless
you used the "all" keyword on the command line.
Enter "done" to leave this mode.

cwd is: /
add *
13 files marked.
$ done
Bootstrap records written to /var/lib/bacula/archive.blablabla.restore.8.bsr

The job will require the following
 Volume(s)                 Storage(s)                SD Device(s)
 ===========================================================================

 Vol0047                   archive2                  FileStorage2
Volumes marked with "*" are online.


13 files selected to be restored.

The defined Restore Job resources are:
 1: first-restore
 2: second-restore
 3: third-restore
 4: fourth-restore
 5: fifth-restore
```

It chooses Storage (archive2) before I choose Restore Job. Looks like it read this config not from restore job definition.

Could anyone help me to understand how to define right storage if it set it before reading job config?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/ is the place to be for questions like these

Comment: thanks for your advice:)

Comment: show your director config, especially restore job definitions